# Different viewmodel for different composable functions inside same activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I read somewhere on stack overflow-

> If you are creating a new app, you can skip using Fragments altogether
> and just use composable functions to represent your screens.

But while using fragments we can have different viewmodels for different fragments/screens..Can we achieve same with composable functions..like single activity, different composable functions for different screen and different viewmodel for different composable functions?if yes,is this ideal approach?

Answer (score 2):

> But while using fragments we can have different viewmodels for different fragments/screens.

In Compose, you use composable functions to display your screens - no need to use fragments anymore.

> Can we achieve same with composable functions..like single activity, different composable functions for different screen and different viewmodel for different composable functions?

You can use different ViewModels for different composable functions if you need them. This is how you can do that:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            DifferentViewModels()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DifferentViewModels() {
    Column {
        FirstComposable()
        SecondComposable()
    }
}

@Composable
fun FirstComposable(firstViewModel: FirstViewModel = viewModel()) {
    Text(firstViewModel.value)
}

@Composable
fun SecondComposable(secondViewModel: SecondViewModel = viewModel()) {
    Text(secondViewModel.value)
}

class FirstViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    val value = "Value from the first View Model"
}

class SecondViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    val value = "Value from the second View Model"
}
```

Make sure to add the ViewModel dependency on your build.gradle(Module) file:

```
// Compose ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha07"
```

> if yes,is this ideal approach?

It depends on your project requirements. If you have different big screens where you need to store many different values and you don't need to share them with different screens, you can use different ViewModels for them.

If the screens are small and/or you need to share values between them, sharing one ViewModel will be the way.

Comment: This actually appears wrong to me: The view models are NOT properly cleared (i.e. onLCeared() method does not seem to be called for me) when  navigating out of the composable which owns the view model.

If I do the same with fragments then the viewmodel lifecycle is maintained properly...

Comment: "The ViewModel is retained as long as the scope is alive. For example, if the composable is used in an activity, viewModel() returns the same instance until the activity is finished or the process is killed." [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#viewmodel)

Comment: And also new view models seem to be created when the screen rotates!

This is VERY BAD!

Does this also happening to all of you guys or am I doing something completely wrong?

I forgot to add: I am also using the compose navigation, may be that is the root cause (otherwise, my usage is the same as in this answer)...

Comment: Actually the code of this answer IS CORRECT if you use it exactly as is. But still dangerous when you use it with the compose navigation: After the first navigation action to different composable, the context is somehow lost and the view models are recreated whenever the screen rotates (before the first composable navigation, it works as expected - i.e. no recreation).

Comment: Also the compose navigation does NOT properly call onCleared() on view models which go out of screen. Based on the missbehavior I experience, I would say that Google is working towards that (to bind the view model lifecycle to the compose navigation properly) but still not there. We probably have to wait for Google to make it more mature...

Comment: You are most probably doing something wrong. The configuration change is something you use view models for in the first place. The implementation of view models inside compose navigation is different. Post your code in a new question where you are having issues. People will answer the proper way.

Comment: Here we go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69064105/android-compose-navigation-avnd-viewmodel-lifecycle

Comment: They will all be scoped to the nearest LifecycleOwner/ViewModelStoreOwner/SavedStateRegistryOwner, which is either the Fragment (if you use them), or the Activity. Alternately, Navigation-Compose sets up the NavBackStackEntry to be the nearest LifecycleOwner/ViewModelStoreOwner/SavedStateRegistryOwner.

Answer (score 0):

CAN you do it? Yes. Should you do it? Depends upon your use case, but not a problem at all.

You may choose to do so, but in such cases, the best option is what keeps your code clean (readable and maintainable). So, if you are creating composables for entire screens, I think it is viable to use multiple viewmodels for each since a lot of data would be stuffed into a single one otherwise. However, you should pay attention to the maintenance of the viewmodels. If you initialize the vm inside the composable, there are chances of it being destroyed (especially if you use navigation). You would have to declare it top-level in the activity itself. Multiple viewmodels in a single activity might not be common in the view world, but there is no issue in doing so. So my suggestion would be to go for what is suitable for your specific use case. If the only thing you wanted to ask was whether it can be done and whether there is any issue in doing so, then your answers are - Yes, and no (respectively).

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter the same problem. By looking the Google sample code [GameViewModel.kt](https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-unscramble/blob/viewmodel/app/src/main/java/com/example/unscramble/ui/GameViewModel.kt), it seems like you will need to clean the data explicitly.

The view model has the init block to clean data

```
init {
    resetGame()
}
```

The same function `resetGame()` is also called when the game is finished.

Or if you are using navigation component, you could rely on `popBackStack`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/70141402/691626